# Why the HTTP code 204 is treated as not successful REST request call?

Tags: java, moshi

We need to consume a third party Rest APIs. Some of their APIs return the 204 code to indicate something is done (correctly). A sample Java REST client code with Moshi,

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    ...
    .put(body)
    .build();                                     
try(Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()){
    if(!response.isSuccessful()){
         int responseCode = response.code();
         // 204 will show up here
     }
}
```

I am wondering why the 204, not content returned, is treated as a unsuccessful request call in Moshi.

Comment: [204 is no content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204), can you share what are the details of the request you're making.

Comment: Could you share the exact error message and perhaps the API you are calling, if sharing more code is possible.

Comment: So `Request` is not a Moshi class ... according to the javadocs.  What exactly is it?  What its fully qualified name?

Comment: I think you are using Retrofit, and `Response` is a class from Retrofit. The `isSuccessful()` method on it `Returns true if {@link #code()} is in the range [200..300)`. So I don't think you would get the `response.code()` as 204 if `isSuccessful()` returned false.

Comment: I update my question to provide more content.

Comment: What's the concrete class of `response`?

Comment: The Response is from Moshi.

Comment: @tgdavies No thing

Comment: Please show the actual package names of the classes in your question -- Request and Response

Comment: The related entries in the pox.xml file are com.squareup.okhttps3:okhttp and com.squareup:moshi.

Answer (score 0):

The successful conclusion of some actions only need a success response, e.g. saving a draft of a document - or toggling a boolean flag like enable/disable.

Returning the entire draft document is redundant, as the client already has the updated content.

In addition, returning a HTTP 204 with no content demands the client create their own success message, if one is desired.

See: https://httpstatuses.com/204